# function is not defined in javascript. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling javascript function from html. But it keeps return error and saying function is not defined in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doforumda/95wqh/).

here is html code

```
<div id="Container">
    <img alt="Click to zoom" class="image" onclick="resizeImg(this)" 
src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Audi-A1.jpg" />
</div>
```

here is javascript

```
function resizeImg (img) {
        var resize = 150; // resize amount in percentage
        var origH  = 61;  // original image height
        var origW  = 250; // original image width
        var mouseX = event.x;
        var mouseY = event.y;
        var newH   = origH * (resize / 100);
        var newW   = origW * (resize / 100);

        // Set the new width and height
        img.style.height = newH;
        img.style.width  = newW;

        var c = img.parentNode;

        // Work out the new center
        c.scrollLeft = (mouseX * (resize / 100)) - (newW / 2) / 2;
        c.scrollTop  = (mouseY * (resize / 100)) - (newH / 2) / 2;
    }
```

Why and how to solve it?

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Comment: Your fiddle is set to execute the JavaScript `onDomready`, so your function isn't declared globally

Comment: JSFiddle is wrapping your function in a DOM ready handler, so it's out of scope. Change your settings, see http://jsfiddle.net/95wqh/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to select `no-wrap in body/head` in the second dropdown in left hand panel.

since you have selected onDomReady, your script is surrounded by `$(function(){...})`
ex

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
function resizeImg (img) {
    var resize = 150; // resize amount in percentage
    var origH  = 61;  // original image height
    var origW  = 250; // original image width
    var mouseX = event.x;
    var mouseY = event.y;
    var newH   = origH * (resize / 100);
    var newW   = origW * (resize / 100);

    // Set the new width and height
    img.style.height = newH;
    img.style.width  = newW;

    var c = img.parentNode;

    // Work out the new center
    c.scrollLeft = (mouseX * (resize / 100)) - (newW / 2) / 2;
    c.scrollTop  = (mouseY * (resize / 100)) - (newH / 2) / 2;
}

});//]]>  

</script>
```

This makes the function `resizeImg` local to the anonymous function passed to `$()`, so it will not be visible to the global scope. when the image is clicked the method will be searched in the global scope where it is not visible that is the reason for the error

Answer (score 1):

you didn't specify "px" in the new height and width and in jsfiddle you have to wrap  it in head section

```
function resizeImg (img) {
    var resize = 150; // resize amount in percentage
    var origH  = 61;  // original image height
    var origW  = 250; // original image width
    var mouseX = event.x;
    var mouseY = event.y;
    var newH   = origH * (resize / 100);
    var newW   = origW * (resize / 100);

    // Set the new width and height
    img.style.height = newH+"px";   // changes made
    img.style.width  = newW+"px";

    var c = img.parentNode;

    // Work out the new center
    c.scrollLeft = (mouseX * (resize / 100)) - (newW / 2) / 2;
    c.scrollTop  = (mouseY * (resize / 100)) - (newH / 2) / 2;
}
```

Working jsfiddle **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/95wqh/4/)**

Hope this helps Thank you